# How to push changes through django?

Tags: python, django

I've been given the keys to a website written in Python on the Django framework.  I have a php background, so I'm not used to having to worry about compliation, etc.

I'm just trying to change the copyright at the footer.  I found the template that holds the html... it's called base.html, in the 'templates' folder.  I changed the copyright from 2010 to 2011, but it's not showing up on the site.

Should I need to recompile anything in order for my changes to show up?

Comment: No.  You don't need to recompile.  Perhaps you should change the question to something a little more open-ended.  "What do I need to do to make the changes visible"?  Might be a better question.  Also, we need to know if there's a `.wsgi` file involved.  That's a sign of `mod_wsgi` being used with Apache, which is important to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an important task ;) Your python scripts (.py) are compiled to bytecode files (.pyc) automatically. If the .py file has changed or there is no .pyc file, your python interpreter will automatically compile.

AFAIK, template files (.html) are not cached in memory. But .pyc files are, and often it is necessary to tell apache to reload. To me, it sounds more like you're changing the wrong .html file or the wrong part of the html code.

With respect to compiling, python is much like php, except that it saves its bytecode for later use.

Comment: template files can be cached in memory if you use jango.template.loaders.cached.Loader

Comment: That task, important but quite minor.  The main issue for me has been wrapping my head around python's eccentricities without bringing down this rather large site for a client.  I've learned much, but still can't find 1) the caching system that makes the templates wait 20 minutes or so to update the changes, and 2) a way to update the .py files and see the changes made live right away.  I don't think restarting the webserver that often is going to be an option.

Comment: @Chase: you need to do your development outside of the server, and only deploy (and restart the server) when it's all ready.

Answer (score 1):

there are two different things.

if you change your python files, it is complicated. most of time, you need restart your server to see changes.

But I think your problem is totally different. You use django.template.loaders.cached.Loader

you can check it in your settings.py

anyway if you use this template loader( I think so), you need to restart your webserver again.

if you don't want to restart your server for template change, you must remove django.template.loaders.cached.Loader from TEMPLATE_LOADERS and restart your server once... because you change your python file. after this step, when you change your template files, see changes without restart.

django docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/